# Map apache2 proxy to different ports

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy

I am running apache 2.2 and have a problem to map two different applications (Plex and Owncloud) on port 80. What I want to do is to proxy example/plex to localhost:32400/web (which is the default setting of plex). Also I want to map example/cloud on localhost/owncloud.

What I have tried so far:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example

  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from 192.168.1.0/24
  </Proxy>

  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off

  ProxyPass /cloud http://127.0.0.1/owncloud/
  ProxyPassReverse /cloud http://127.0.0.1/owncloud/

  <Location /plex/>
    ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:32400/web/
    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:32400/web/
  </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

That works for the cloud => owncloud proxy, but for some reason, whatever I try it doesn´t work for the Plex with port 32400.

I also tried with this instead of the Location block:

```
 ProxyPass /plex http://127.0.0.1:32400/web/
 ProxyPassReverse /plex http://127.0.0.1:32400/web/
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tangentially, I'd suggest using the same syntax for both proxy entries: Either `ProxyPass (target)` in a `Location` block or `ProxyPass source target` without a location block.

Comment: You say you want to pass to `127.0.0.1:32400/web` and your config shows you mapping to `127.0.0.1:32400/`, is one of those a typo?

Comment: Ah, sorry. No it isnt, was just changing and trying a lot. Before I had it different. Regarding the location block: Before I had it without, and it also didn´t work :( I updated the starting post, thanks for the hints!

Comment: Does nobody have an idea? ;(